# How to define a shortcut for a set of keys in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

I am not sure what is the right terminology here, so let me explain by means of an example. Suppose I have bib file containing four papers (actual number is larger, but I want to a small MWE):

```
@article{paper1,
   title={Paper 1},
   author={Author 1},
   journal={Journal 1},
}

@article{paper2,
   title={Paper 2},
   author={Author 2},
   journal={Journal 2},
}

@article{paper3,
   title={Paper 3},
   author={Author 3},
   journal={Journal 3},
}

@article{paper4,
   title={Paper 4},
   author={Author 4},
   journal={Journal 4},
}
```

Suppose `paper1` and `paper2` belong to one topic, say `topic1`; and `paper3` and `paper4` belong to another topic, say `topic2`. Is it possible to define `topic1` and `topic2` keys (either at the bibtex end or at latex end) so that the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Topic 1 has been investigated in~\cite{topic1}. Topic 2 has been investigated
in~\cite{topic2}. However, \cite{topic1, topic2} do not take feature 1 into
consideration.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test-bib}
\end{document}
```

In particular, I want this to be equivalent to:

```
Topic 1 has been investigated in~\cite{paper1, paper2}. Topic 2 has been
investigated in~\cite{paper3, paper4}. However, \cite{paper1, paper2, 
paper3, paper4} do not take feature 1 into consideration.
```

Note that I do not want the appearance of the references to change.

Comment: Are you looking perhaps for `mcite`/`mciteplus`/entry sets in `biblatex`?

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks for the hint. What I am looking for is exactly equivalent to `\defbibentryset` in `biblatex` (except perhaps that all defined sets are included in the bibliography, but that is a minor issue). Is there a similar solution for `bibtex`; otherwise, I guess it is time for me to finally move to `biblatex`.

Comment: @JosephWright: Sorry, I take that back. This is not the behaviour that I want. What I am looking for is a shortcut when citing multiple citations, but the bibliography should appear as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expl3`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{paper1,
   title={Paper 1},
   author={Author 1},
   journal={Journal 1},
}

@article{paper2,
   title={Paper 2},
   author={Author 2},
   journal={Journal 2},
}

@article{paper3,
   title={Paper 3},
   author={Author 3},
   journal={Journal 3},
}

@article{paper4,
   title={Paper 4},
   author={Author 4},
   journal={Journal 4},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_aditya_tcite_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\tcite}{m}
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l_aditya_tcite_clist
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \aditya_process_topic:n { ##1 }
   }
  \aditya_cite:V \l_aditya_tcite_clist
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\newtopic}{mm}
 {
  \clist_new:c { g_aditya_topic_#1_clist }
  \clist_gset:cn { g_aditya_topic_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \aditya_process_topic:n
 {
  \clist_put_right:Nv \l_aditya_tcite_clist { g_aditya_topic_#1_clist }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \aditya_cite:n
 {
  \cite{#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \aditya_cite:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_put_right:Nn { Nv }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtopic{topic1}{paper1,paper2}
\newtopic{topic2}{paper3,paper4}

\begin{document}

Topic 1 has been investigated in~\tcite{topic1}. Topic 2 has been investigated
in~\tcite{topic2}. However, \tcite{topic1, topic2} do not take feature 1 into
consideration.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Every `\newtopic` command defines a clist variable; within `\tcite` every item in the comma separated list given as argument is expanded to the clist it refers to and appended to a temporary clist, then `\cite` is called on the so formed clist.

I use the fact that clists are normalized when built to have no spaces on either side of each item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a partial solution. I can simply define macros

```
\def\topicA{paper1,paper2}
\def\topicB{paper3,paper4}
```

and then use

```
\cite{\topicA} and \cite{\topicB}
```

However, `\cite{\topicA,\topicB}` does not work (the aux file contains `\citation{paper3,paper4}`, so the expansion happens late). So, I simply copied the `\expanded` macro from ConTeXt (is there a LaTeX macro with the same features?); to avoid name clash I called it `\contextexpanded` and then `\contextexpaned{\cite{\topicA,\topicB}}` works. Here is a complete example:

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\contextexpanded#1%
    {\xdef\helper@expanded{\noexpand#1}\helper@expanded}
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\def\topicA{paper1,paper2}
\def\topicB{paper3,paper4}
\begin{document}

Topic 1 has been investigated in~\cite{\topicA}. Topic 2 has been investigated
in~\cite{\topicB}. However, \contextexpanded{\cite{\topicA,\topicB}} do
not take feature 1 into consideration.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test-bib}
\end{document}
```

I am still interested in knowing if there is a simpler (or more LaTeX-ish) solution.